# Non isomorphic subgroups of cyclic groups

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

let *G* be a cyclic group of order 12. find number of non isomorphic subgroups of *G*. 
How to approach such questions?

Comment: In the future please make an effort to add more context to your Questions.  For example, show an example of two such subgroups, or share why you find the problem an interesting one.

Comment: So, we can conclude (from above answers) that simplest formula to obtain number of nonisomorphic subgroups of cyclic group of order n is tau(n). Where tau(n) is number of positive divisors of n. You can easily calculate it for n if ypu know the prime factorisation and simple properties of tau function. This question was asked in IIT JAM2016 right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The results of cyclic groups are (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group#Subgroups_and_notation):

All the subgroups of cyclic groups are cyclic, for every $n$ dividing the group order there is a cyclic subgroup of order $n$  and all cyclic groups of the same order are isomorphic.

So for a cyclic group of order 12 we have exactly 6 pairwise non isomorphic subgroups, which are isomorphic to cyclic groups of order $1,2,3,4,6,12$. This are all subgroups by Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: Does the improper subgroup G itself and the trivial subgroup count as a non-isomorphic subgroup or do we have to exclude them to get 4 as our answer?

Answer (score 2):

In a cyclic group of order $n$, there is exactly one subgroup of order $d$ for each divisor $d$ of $n$.

Groups of different order cannot be isomorphic.

Therefore, the number of non-isomorphic subgroups of $G$ is the number of divisors of $n$.